# Temperature bounds in heat transfer PDE

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, laplacian

I have a heat transfer problem with solution in an arbitrary domain $\Omega$ given by
\begin{equation}T(x,t)=T_{\infty}(x)+\sum_{n=0}c_n X_n(x) e^{-\lambda_n t} \end{equation}
where $T_{\infty}(x)$ is the steady-state solution, $X_n(x)$ and $\lambda_n$ are the Laplacian eigen-functions and eigen-values, and $c_n$ are coefficients obtained from the initial condition $T_0(x)$ such that:
\begin{equation}\sum_{n=0}c_n X_n(x) =T_0(x) - T_{\infty}(x) \end{equation}
If we know that $T_{\infty}(x) > T_{0}(x) \quad \forall x \in \Omega$, is it possible to show that the temperature evolution in time will always be bounded by the initial and steady state temperatures?
\begin{equation} T_{\infty}(x) \geq T(x,t) \geq  T_0(x) \quad \forall t \in [0,\infty)\end{equation}

**Edit 1:** The original problem is the following:
\begin{equation}
c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T) + g(x) \\
T(x,0)=T_0(x) \\
T=T_D(x)\;\mathrm{on}\;\Gamma_D \quad -k\nabla T \cdot n=q_N \; \mathrm{on} \; \Gamma_N \quad k\nabla T \cdot n + h(T-T_f(x)=0 \; \mathrm{on} \; \Gamma_R
\end{equation}
where $g(x)$ is a heat source. $T_{\infty}(x)$ solves the steady-state part of the temperature including the time-independent heat source and non-honogeneous boundary conditions.
\begin{equation}
-\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T_{\infty}) = g(x) \\
T_{\infty}=T_D(x)\;\mathrm{on}\;\Gamma_D \quad -k\nabla T_{\infty} \cdot n=q_N \; \mathrm{on} \; \Gamma_N \quad k\nabla T_{\infty} \cdot n + h(T_{\infty}-T_f(x))=0 \; \mathrm{on} \; \Gamma_R
\end{equation}

Comment: Your condition eq(2) is rather stringent.  Normally you would have "hot" spots that cool down and "cold" spots that heat up.   i.e. the "hot" spots need to be maintained at a constant temperature.  Otherwise, you have things like entropic reduction and/or conflicts with the second law of thermodynamics.   In other words, you would have to be supplying energy faster than it is leaking away from sources.

Comment: I have a time-independent heat source that drives the temperature distribution in the steady state, hence the assumption $T_{\infty}(x) > T_{0}(x) \quad \forall x \in \Omega$ seems reasonable to me. In principle, I don't see any thermodynamic violation in the problem.

Comment: I see, and I have had a similar problem from time to time :)  You want to know you don't cook biological specimens while trying to heat them up in a hurry for a test.  I knew of a way to transform an exponential time series into an orthogonal representation/series.  And then I think Parseval's theorem would be applicable.  I will try to find the papers (it's been twenty years) and see if my memory is serving me correctly, or if I can stumble upon them.

Comment: Thanks @rrogers. Yes, I basically want to prove that for constant heat source and boundary conditions the highest temperature will be reached in the steady state so that I can forget about the intermediate time instants.

Comment: I found the math's that deals (?) with your type of series; MUNTZ or  MUNTZ–GALERKIN polynomials.   The most generic papers I have are by P. Borwein, but here are two other papers that deal with things that "look like" your problem: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~shen7/pub/SW16.pdf  and https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-218-00/S0002-9947-1976-0399705-1/S0002-9947-1976-0399705-1.pdf .  Just guesses, in case you want to try these yourself instead of waiting for my (slow) research.  It's been awhile.

Comment: BTW: you have to change your "powered" terms from exp(-\lambda*t) to exp(-t)^(\lambda) to be compatible; i.e. x<1  in the paper/Muntz terms.  So that the range [0,inf] is mapped to [1,0] .

Comment: I think I can prove your point but I need the domain definitions; for instance $\Gamma_{D}$ and the associated functions; q_n and such.  Basically, we can examine the slope of the derivative of T to see if it can ever change sign.  For the individual Eigenfunctions on x, they can't but I don't haven't seen a way clear for mixing the negative and positive coefficients.

Comment: I agree, but I don't have any particular definition in mind for $\Gamma_D$ or $q_N$; the only constraint being that the boundary conditions do not depend on time. On the other hand, I think this problem is similar to the following one: given the linear system of ODEs $\dot{x} + Ax = 0 \quad x(0)=x_0$, with $A$ symmetric and positive-definite, prove that if $x_{0,i}>0 \quad \forall i$ then $x_{0,i}>x_i(t)>0 \quad \forall i, t \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry, but this is beyond me.  The only actual reference I found was: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965999002104  
Which deals with strictly monotone 1-d.  The idea of finding non-monotone "turning points" still has to be evaluated to be T>Tinf .  I am reasonably sure I can manipulate T(x,0) and boundary conditions to produce both monotonic evolutions diff(T(x,t),x,2)=0 that are inside or outside the T(x,inf) condition.  But they are examples and don't have defined boundaries.  But I am interested, if you come up with further work/references; please let me know.

Comment: However, there is this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.01949.pdf,  which I don't understand well enough to comment on its relevance.